# Conditional transform on pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a very simple problem, but I can't seem to get it right.
Consider this dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group' : 
               ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'time' : [20, 21, 22, 20, 21],
               'price' : [3.1, 3.5, 3.0, 2.3, 2.1]})


   group price time
0   A   3.1     20
1   A   3.5     21
2   A   3.0     22
3   B   2.3     20
4   B   2.1     21
```

Now I want to take the standard deviation of the price of each group, but conditional on it being before time 22 (let's call it `early_std`). I want to then create a variable with that information.

The expected result is

```
group price time    early_std

A   3.1     20      0.282843
A   3.5     21      0.282843
A   3.0     22      0.282843
B   2.3     20      0.141421
B   2.1     21      0.141421
```

This is what I tried:

```
df['early_std'] = df[df.time < 22].groupby('group').\
price.transform(lambda x : x.std())
```

This almost works but it gives a missing value on `time = 22`:

```
 group price    time early_std
0   A   3.1     20  0.282843
1   A   3.5     21  0.282843
2   A   3.0     22  NaN
3   B   2.3     20  0.141421
4   B   2.1     21  0.141421
```

I also tried with apply and I think it works, but I need to reset the index, which is something I'd rather avoid (I have a large dataset and I need to do this repeatedly)

```
early_std2 = df[df.time < 22].groupby('group').price.std()

df.set_index('group', inplace=True)
df['early_std2'] = early_std2

    price   time early_std  early_std2
group               
A   3.1     20  0.282843    0.282843
A   3.5     21  0.282843    0.282843
A   3.0     22  NaN         0.282843
B   2.3     20  0.141421    0.141421
B   2.1     21  0.141421    0.141421
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear what results do you expect to see in the rows where `time>=22`. Can you clarify, please.

Comment: @Primer : I've edited my question to explicitly include the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you only need to add `fillna()` to your first code to expand the `std` values:

```
df['early_std'] = df[df.time < 22].groupby('group')['price'].transform(pd.Series.std)
df['early_std'] = df.groupby('group')['early_std'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.max()))
df
```

To get:

```
  group  price  time  early_std
0     A    3.1    20      0.283
1     A    3.5    21      0.283
2     A    3.0    22      0.283
3     B    2.3    20      0.141
4     B    2.1    21      0.141
```

EDIT: I have changed `ffill` to a more general `fillna`, but you could also use chained `.bfill().ffill()` to achieve the same result.

Comment: thanks a bunch. Let me think if this works generally first and then I'll accept your answer (please remind me if I forget)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: any reason you prefer `pd.Series.std` instead of  `x.std`  inside the `transform` ?

Comment: This is just a matter of style preference. There should not be any performance advantages, so you can use this or `lambda x: x.std()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach is very close to what you are trying to achieve.
This may not be the most efficient method but it worked for me:

```
df['early_std'] = 0
for index,value in early_std2.iteritems():
    df.early_std[df.group==index] = value
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I think iterating like that is only recommended when all other options are exhausted. I have a large dataset, so efficiency does matter to me!